# Can I use getops to define a dynamic construction for a command?

Tags: bash, awk

I am really new to bash and I am trying to write a basic script that will parse a file and store certain awk'ed elements in an array, to be printed side by side in a columnar fashion. I have the arrays defined and the command working, but I would like to use getops to define the output. Apologies if I am not clear, but hopefully the psedocode will explain.

Cheers for any help, Scott

```
#!/bin/bash

# Defined arrays
INPUTFILE=$2
ARRAYA=$(Code to process a file and extract column A)
ARRAYB=$(Code to process a file and extract column B)
ARRAYC=$(Code to process a file and extract column C)
ARRAYD=$(Code to process a file and extract column D)

# Define getops arguments
while getopts "A:B:C:D:" arg; do
     case $arg in
         A)
       "I want to use $ARRAYA"
       shift
       ;;
         B)
       "I want to use $ARRAYB"
       shift
       ;;
         C)
       "I want to use $ARRAYC"
       shift
           ;;
         D)
       "I want to use $ARRAYD"
       shift
           ;;
    esac
done

# Sample command construction for "myscript.sh -ABCD $INPUTFILE"
for ((i=0; i<=${#ARRAYA[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "${ARRAYA[i]}" "${ARRAYB[i]}" "${ARRAYC[i]}" "${ARRAYD[i]}"
done

# Sample command construction for "myscript.sh -DCB $INPUTFILE"
for ((i=0; i<=${#ARRAYD[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "${ARRAYD[i]}" "${ARRAYC[i]}" "${ARRAYB[i]}"
done
```

Comment: good start, but please include expected inputs (keep it simplified), and the expected outputs from those inputs. Good luck.

Comment: It's highly likely that you're approaching this the wrong way. The shell is an environment from which to call tools. awk is the standard UNIX tool to parse text files. Rather than trying to do some processing in shell and have it call awk for others, the right approach is almost certainly to just do it all in awk.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, it is possibly clumsy, but I need to do some additional processing on the log files after. The answer from Glenn below does what I want, but prints it in a single linear row, rather than in 4 columns. It gets me over my hurdle though, which is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the ugliness: uses bash indirect variables

```
#!/bin/bash

ARRAYA=( a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 )
ARRAYB=( b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 )
ARRAYC=( c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 )
ARRAYD=( d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 )

order=()
while getopts ":ABCD" arg; do
     case $arg in
         A) order+=("ARRAYA") ;;
         B) order+=("ARRAYB") ;;
         C) order+=("ARRAYC") ;;
         D) order+=("ARRAYD") ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

(( ${#order[@]} == 0 )) && exit

for ((i=0; i<=${#ARRAYA[@]}; i++)); do
    for ary in "${order[@]}"; do
        elem="${ary}[$i]"
        echo -n "${!elem} "
    done
    echo
done
```

Testing:

```
$ bash abcd.sh -A
a1 
a2 
a3 
a4 
a5 

$ bash abcd.sh -BA
b1 a1 
b2 a2 
b3 a3 
b4 a4 
b5 a5 

$ bash abcd.sh -BAC
b1 a1 c1 
b2 a2 c2 
b3 a3 c3 
b4 a4 c4 
b5 a5 c5 

$ bash abcd.sh -DCBA
d1 c1 b1 a1 
d2 c2 b2 a2 
d3 c3 b3 a3 
d4 c4 b4 a4 
d5 c5 b5 a5 

$ bash abcd.sh 
(no output)
```

Comment: Cheers Glenn, that is exactly what I was trying to do. I'm sure it is not the nicest way, but once I have the output I need I can clean it up. Hopefully I can keep up my Bash learning and you helped me get over my current hurdle!

Comment: I see now why I am getting different results. The array above is a row and my array is a column. Something interesting for me to dig further in to... :-)